# How to customize console deployment view in eclipse dark theme?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-neon

I am unable to customize Eclipse Dev Dark theme console deployment view. Image that has font color in blue:

[image: Eclipse DEV dark theme console view]

How to change the font of deployment view?

I am able to change the console font normally but not the font of deployment view in console.